# cant import project from github

Tags: android, github

I downloaded this project: 
https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

I wanted to import it into my android studio but i get an error which says:

> "Gradle Sync project failed"

and messages Gradle Sync says:

> Error:(63, 0) /Users/zooky/AndroidStudioProjects/QuickReturn-master/app/signing.properties (No such file or directory)

the directory indeed doesn't exist but since I downloaded it from Github it has to be like that i guess. anyone knows a solution?

Comment: try to remove this line:   `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` in `app/build.gradle` there is also a information on the last lines of the build.gralde file.... `// Extract signing info into a properties file`

Comment: well i deleted that line and this: ef props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(project.file("signing.properties")))
android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile project.file(props.keyStore)
android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword props.keyStorePassword
android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias props.keyAlias
android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword props.keyAliasPassword          now it works..not sure if i did the right thing :D

Comment: ok now it doenst work :S